# Logsash - Collecting Fortigate Logs

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I've got ELK pulling logs from all my Windows servers and its running great. Working on getting my Fortigate logs in there and I'm having trouble. Here is what I've done so far:

On the Fortigate:

```
config log syslogd setting
    set status enable
    set server "ip of my logstash server"
    set port 5044
end
config log syslogd filter
    set severity warning
end
```

On the ELK server, under /etc/logstash/conf.d I added a new file named "20-fortigate-filter.conf with the following contents:

```
filter {
  kv {
    add_tag => ["fortigate"]
  }
}
```

Then restarted the logstash and kibana services. But I'm not finding the logs in Kibana anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you send your logs from your windows servers? Perhaps it's just a  missing input in your logstash configuration (from your info, it could be `syslog {port => 5044 }` )

Comment: Using winlogbeats on the Windows servers. They are all pointing to 5044 and making it through.

Comment: Ok. I don't know what the problem can be. Sorry I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify "field_split" and "value_split" too,

try this:

```
kv {
add_tag => ["fortigate"]
value_split => "="
field_split => ","
}
```

**note: enable csv in fortigate syslog.**